# VBA read text file into Excel spreadsheet based on criteria

Tags: vba, criteria

Folks, I am trying to read what is a very large space delimited text file into an Excel spreadsheet using VBA.  The text file contains 5 columns of data which are delimited by multiple spaces.  I have managed to open the file and split the file into various columns.  Now I would like to choose only rows that meet certain criteria as output into the spreadsheet.  So, for example, i would like to choose only the rows which in the first column are DIES and in the second column are EUR.  Any advice on how to efficiently accomplish this?  I've tried various combinations with If/Else statements but this not seem to work.  Thank you.

Text file

```
DIES         EUR         REFGR       OCT2008                    847.000 
VARS         EUR         REFGR       NOV2008                    154.000 
EFFS         OECD        REFGR       DEC2008                    507.000 
DIES         EUR         REFGR       JAN2008                    090.000 
USUE         EUR         REFGR       FEB2008                    836.000
```

And my code so far

```
Sub ImportData()

Open "FileName" For Input As #1

lRow = 2

Do While Not EOF(1)
    Line Input #1, Data
    Data = Application.WorksheetFunction.Trim(Data)           
sData = Split(Data, " ")                                    

    With Sheet1
        lColumn = 2
        For intCount = LBound(sData) To UBound(sData)
            .Cells(lRow, lColumn) = sData(intCount)
            lColumn = lColumn + 1
        Next intCount
    End With
    lRow = lRow + 1

Loop

Close #1


End Sub
```

Comment: Is that space-delimited or is it fixed-width?  Looks more like fixed-width if your example is representative. You might be better off using `Trim(Mid(...))` to pull each field out individually from the line. Once you have them split out you just check the first two values to decide whether or not to write them to the sheet.

Comment: see this [walkthrough about how to read a *.txt file in VBA](http://vba4all.wordpress.com/category/vba-macros/reading-txt-files-from-vba/)

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, treat the text file as a data source and query it.

Using DAO:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-au/library/aa293458(v=vs.60).aspx

Using ADO: 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms974559.aspx

Comment: Yes it is indeed fixed-with....I will give the data source approach a try as it might make the whole thing run faster....the text files are several million rows long with a few hundred columns, I was finding that the line input method was not very fast.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I would go for something like that. You can write a function that decides if a row should or should not be written to the file.

```
function IsValid(stringArray as string()) as boolean
    ' Your criteria goes here, maybe with case/switches or lots of ifs
end function
```

Then your code would be like:

```
...
With Sheet1
    lColumn = 2
    if IsValid(sData) then
        For intCount = LBound(sData) To UBound(sData)
            .Cells(lRow, lColumn) = sData(intCount)
            lColumn = lColumn + 1
        Next intCount
    end if
End With
....
```

If you are having problems with the layout of your conditionals, you need to provide more info about then so we can help =).

Comment: Here is the layout of my conditional, using IF to try to select rows where 1st column in each row matches DIES, this isn't working however.  Any suggestions?  If sData(1) = GASDIES Then
                
                For intCount = LBound(sData) To UBound(sData)
                    .Cells(lRow, lColumn) = sData(intCount)
                    lColumn = lColumn + 1
                Next intCount
        End If
        End With